# MySQL, Selecting a group of elements by ID?

Tags: mysql

I've got a script that pulls the ID from each row, and you can select from these to change multiple at the same time.

I have an array of the ID's to update, but how do I select a group of arbitrary ID's in a single mysql query?

Something like:

`SELECT * FROM 'locations' WHERE 'region'='$region' AND 'uniqueID'={$id_array}`

I'm a bit confused on this, i'm sure mysql has a special operator for this sort of thing. Or does it? Would I be better off just doing a separate mysql query for each element? (If so, can I tie multiple queries in to a single PHP mysql call?... to reduce connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM 'localtions' WHERE 'uniqueID' IN (.....your ids here, comma separated)`

For a PHP solution:
`WHERE uniqueid IN (" . implode($id_list, ",") . ")`

Comment: Ugh, damn you "IN" keyword... I couldn't find it in the manual for the life of me. Looks to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks. (Now to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer...)

Comment: The `IN` keyword is actually T-SQL (flavor agnostic), so wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't in a MySQL specific manual. Not that I looked it up however.

Comment: This is the solution I used in the end. I comma separated the array using implode: `..."WHERE uniqueid IN (" . implode($id_list, ',') . ")"`

Comment: Added PHP solution to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing multiple connection to database you can make a comma separated id string and fire the in query.

```
foreach ($arr as $id_array) {
$strid .= ','.$arr;
```

}

which will give you the comma separated ids string. 
Now you need to connect to database once only.

```
SELECT * FROM 'locations' WHERE 'region'='$region' AND 'uniqueID' in (."$strid".)
```

Comment: Thanks, but hkf beat you to it. I ended up using implode() to combine my array into a comma separated string.